Determining previous sort option in cursor pagination
I'm implementing cursor pagination . I need to provide two sorting options , which is date and priority . I use date and priority respectively as cursor value to paginate , for the options . When the user  changes sort option after second or x page , how do I determine the sorting is changed  ??
1st request from client :
Sorting option--DateTime
nextCursor :2024-07-24T10:37:43Z
2nd request from client :
Sorting option--priority
nextCursor:2024-07-24T10:37:43Z
I need to sort the records based on new sort , when the sort changed(irrespective the next cursor value)  , it can move to first page of new sorting .
